# How to add the name of the processed image to the .csv output file?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to append the name of image which has been processed in Python to the output .csv file. And to put the  results of the next image processing to the other .csv vertical column or horizontal row.

How? Here is the code:

```
 def humoments(self):               #function for HuMoments computation
     for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
         img = cv.LoadImageM(filename, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
         cancer = cv.GetHuMoments(cv.Moments(img))
         #arr = cancer
         arr = numpy.array([cancer])
     with open('hu.csv', 'wb') as csvfile: #puts the array to file
         for elem in arr.flat[:50]:
             writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',      quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
             writer.writerow([('{}\t'.format(elem))])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to collect all your data in a list or array and then write it to the csv file row by row. Here's an example:

```
import csv
import numpy

allFileNames = [];
allArrs = [];
for i in range(10):
    arr = i * numpy.ones((5,5)) # fake data as an example
    filename = 'file ' + str(i) # fake file names

    allFileNames.append(filename) # keep track of the file name
    allArrs.append(list(arr.flatten())) # keep track of the data

with open('hu.csv', 'wb') as csvfile: #puts the array to file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # write file names to the first row
    writer.writerow(allFileNames)

    # transpose arrs so each list corresponds to a column of the csv file.
    rows = map(list, zip(*allArrs))

    #write array to file
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

This will give you a csv file with the file name at the top of each column and the corresponding data below it.